# Passing dynamic parameter to similar function

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function that runs other functions ( inner functions ). So each inner function is step of main function.
I have to update progress each time inner function end to run. Each inner function accepts current progress as parameter and i do that manually.

Problem is that i have about 10 main function while number of inner function of each main function changes.

Is there a way to introduce dynamic value of some kind in this flow ?

Example:

```
public void Run() {
DoWork1(33);
DoWork2(66);
Dowork3(100);
}

public void Run() {
DoWork1(25);
DoWork4(50);
Dowork5(75);
Dowork2(100);
}
```

Comment: How (and in what order) do you run your main functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not *really* clear what you mean, but perhaps you want:

```
public void Run(params Action<int>[] actions)
{      
    for (int i = 0; i < actions.Length; i++)
    {
        Action<int> action = actions[i];
        int progress = ((i + 1) * 100) / actions.Length;
        action(progress);
    }
}
```

Then call it with:

```
Run(DoWork1, DoWork2, DoWork3);

Run(DoWork1, DoWork4, DoWork5, DoWork2);
```

Comment: Where do you take "action" ? Shouldn't it be foreach with counter ?

Comment: @eugeneK: Sorry, I originally had a foreach loop, then realized I needed the counter. Edited :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, cool thanks. Just one note, will it be somehow valid ifcertain DoWork() accept more than one parameter?

Comment: You mean `Action<int> action = actions[i];`. :-)

Comment: @eugeneK: No - how would `Run` possibly know what arguments to pass in?